# MySQL query too long in vba

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have an insert MySQL query that is too long and I get error probably because I am not breaking them properly.

so here's the query

```
sq = "Insert into trainer (`ID`, `Site work being carried out`, `Manufacturers Serial Number or VIN`,`Platform`,`Type of Equipment`,`Equipment Sub-Grouping`,`Equipment Group`,`Equipment Description`,`NSN / Part Number`,`Manufacturer`,`Model`,`Date of Manufacture`,`Base`,`On Base Location`,`Serial Number`,`Last Odometer or Hour Meter Reading`,`Current Status`,`Equipment Arrival Date`,`Equipment ECD (Estimated Completion Date)`,`Revised Estimated Delivery Date`,`Equipment ACD  (Actual Equipment Completion Date)`,`Delivered Date`,`Equipment In Program for Repair or Refurbishment`,`Remarks`,`Date Requested Induction of Equipment`,`Date Equipment Inducted into Site / Program`,`Diagnosing Start Date`,`Diagnosing End Date`,`Date Price Parts Sourcing Start`,`Date Price Parts Sourcing End`,`Date NTE Process Starts`,`Induction Cycle Process Complete Date`,`Date Proposal Sent `, `S O issued Date`,`S O No`,`Date PO Request Sent to Procurement`,`Date Foregin / International Parts Arrived at Customs`,`Date Last Part(s) Recvd at Site (last part recvd to start work)`,`Date Repair Started (After last part was recvd at site)`,`Date Repair Completed`,`Local Parts Ordered`,`Local Parts Received`,`Foreign / Int Parts Ordered`,`Foreign / Int Parts Received`) values ('" & prr.value & "','" & sitecombo.value & "','" & vin.value & "','" & ComboBox2.value & "','" & ComboBox3.value & "','" & ComboBox4.value & "','" & eqgrp.value & "','" & desc.value & "','" & nsn.value & "','" & mfg.value & "','" & mdl.value & "','" & mfgyr.value & "','" & rsafbase.value & " ','" & onbaseloc.value & "','" & rsafsr.value & "','" & odomtr.value & "','" & status.value & "','" & arvldt.value & "','" & ecd.value & "','" & redd.value & "','" & acd.value & "','" & deldt.value & "','" & vin.value & "','" & rprrfb.value & "','" & remarks.value & "','" & indreq.value & "','" & inddt.value & "','" & digdt.value & "','" & digend.value & "','" & srcdt.value & "','" & srcend.value & "','" & ntedt.value & "','" & incend.value & "','" & nteprp.value & "','" & nteapp.value & "','" & nteend.value & "','" & sodt.value & "','" & sono.value & "','" & podt.value & "','" & farvl.value & "','" & lstpartrecdt.value & "','" & rprstrt.value & "','" & rprcom.value & "','" & lclord.value & "', '" & lclrec.value & "','" & ford.value & "','" & frec.value & "');"
```

can someone help me please...

Comment: try stringa = stringb + _    stringc+stringd  using the _ as a line continuation.

Comment: Add the original error message. Where it is to Long in mysql or in vba?

Comment: excel vba..I am not sure how to break the query in vba

Comment: error msg--invalid character `

Comment: You can try breaking the query down into sub components. Use two different queries that each select half the data plus one primary key, then run a third query that joins those two on the key.

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem if you [parameterized your query](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado/12354/creating-parametrized-commands#t=201609011302282883276) like you should...